# OverFlow on form tags

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

So i am using bootstrap-vue, and precisely i am using the Form-tag as it's what i exactly needs. The issue is that the dropdown is as the long as the list of options.
Here's what i mean : 
[Tag button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDdlW.png)
& the
[Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN1pN.png)
What i actually want is a similar css to overflow:scroll but i can't seem to make it work.
here's the code :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-group label="Tagged input using dropdown">
      <b-form-tags v-model="value" no-outer-focus class="mb-2">
        <template v-slot="{ tags, disabled, addTag, removeTag }">
          <ul v-if="tags.length > 0" class="list-inline d-inline-block mb-2">
            <li v-for="tag in tags" :key="tag" class="list-inline-item">
              <b-form-tag
                @remove="removeTag(tag)"
                :title="tag"
                :disabled="disabled"
                variant="info"
              >{{ tag }}</b-form-tag>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <b-dropdown size="sm" variant="outline-secondary" block menu-class="w-100">
            <template v-slot:button-content>
              <b-icon icon="tag-fill"></b-icon> Choose tags
            </template>
            <b-dropdown-form @submit.stop.prevent="() => {}">
              <b-form-group
                label-for="tag-search-input"
                label="Search tags"
                label-cols-md="auto"
                class="mb-0"
                label-size="sm"
                :description="searchDesc"
                :disabled="disabled"
              >
                <b-form-input
                  v-model="search"
                  id="tag-search-input"
                  type="search"
                  size="sm"
                  autocomplete="off"
                 ></b-form-input>
              </b-form-group>
            </b-dropdown-form>
            <b-dropdown-divider></b-dropdown-divider>
            <b-dropdown-item-button
              v-for="option in availableOptions"
              :key="option"
              @click="onOptionClick({ option, addTag })"
            >
              {{ option }}
            </b-dropdown-item-button>
            <b-dropdown-text v-if="availableOptions.length === 0">
              There are no tags available to select
            </b-dropdown-text>
          </b-dropdown>
        </template>
      </b-form-tags>
    </b-form-group>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        options: ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Lime', 'Peach', 'Chocolate', 'Strawberry'],
        search: '',
        value: []
      }
    },
    computed: {
      criteria() {
        // Compute the search criteria
        return this.search.trim().toLowerCase()
      },
      availableOptions() {
        const criteria = this.criteria
        // Filter out already selected options
        const options = this.options.filter(opt => this.value.indexOf(opt) === -1)
        if (criteria) {
          // Show only options that match criteria
          return options.filter(opt => opt.toLowerCase().indexOf(criteria) > -1);
        }
        // Show all options available
        return options
      },
      searchDesc() {
        if (this.criteria && this.availableOptions.length === 0) {
          return 'There are no tags matching your search criteria'
        }
        return ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onOptionClick({ option, addTag }) {
        addTag(option)
        this.search = ''
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

If you could please help me... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i did it with adding a div with the following css

```
#test{
   max-height:500px;
   overflow:auto; 
}
```

here's the code if anyone need it :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-group label="Tagged input using dropdown">
      <b-form-tags v-model="value" no-outer-focus class="mb-2">
        <template v-slot="{ tags, disabled, addTag, removeTag }">
          <ul v-if="tags.length > 0" class="list-inline d-inline-block mb-2">
            <li v-for="tag in tags" :key="tag" class="list-inline-item">
              <b-form-tag
                @remove="removeTag(tag)"
                :title="tag"
                :disabled="disabled"
                variant="info"
              >{{ tag }}</b-form-tag>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <b-dropdown size="sm" variant="outline-secondary" block menu-class="w-100">
            <template v-slot:button-content>
              <b-icon icon="tag-fill"></b-icon> Choose tags
            </template>
           <div id="test">
            <b-dropdown-form @submit.stop.prevent="() => {}">
              <b-form-group
                label-for="tag-search-input"
                label="Search tags"
                label-cols-md="auto"
                class="mb-0"
                label-size="sm"
                :description="searchDesc"
                :disabled="disabled"
              >
                <b-form-input
                  v-model="search"
                  id="tag-search-input"
                  type="search"
                  size="sm"
                  autocomplete="off"
                 ></b-form-input>
              </b-form-group>
            </b-dropdown-form>
            <b-dropdown-divider></b-dropdown-divider>
            <b-dropdown-item-button
              v-for="option in availableOptions"
              :key="option"
              @click="onOptionClick({ option, addTag })"
            >
              {{ option }}
            </b-dropdown-item-button>
            <b-dropdown-text v-if="availableOptions.length === 0">
              There are no tags available to select
            </b-dropdown-text>
          </div>
          </b-dropdown>
        </template>
      </b-form-tags>
    </b-form-group>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        options: ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Lime', 'Peach', 'Chocolate', 'Strawberry'],
        search: '',
        value: []
      }
    },
    computed: {
      criteria() {
        // Compute the search criteria
        return this.search.trim().toLowerCase()
      },
      availableOptions() {
        const criteria = this.criteria
        // Filter out already selected options
        const options = this.options.filter(opt => this.value.indexOf(opt) === -1)
        if (criteria) {
          // Show only options that match criteria
          return options.filter(opt => opt.toLowerCase().indexOf(criteria) > -1);
        }
        // Show all options available
        return options
      },
      searchDesc() {
        if (this.criteria && this.availableOptions.length === 0) {
          return 'There are no tags matching your search criteria'
        }
        return ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onOptionClick({ option, addTag }) {
        addTag(option)
        this.search = ''
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```